# RShiny- DT::renderDataTable works locally on server console (No Error Logs) but disconnect when someone using link

Tags: r, shiny, jquery-ui-sortable, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am facing issues with DT::renderDataTable with reactive function (which I am using to select Drag and Drop columns to filter selected columns to show on UI). It works locally on console but disconnect when I am running on RServer using link. It breaks when it was trying to populate dataframe on UI. All package versions are same and I am using R 3.6.1. There are no Error logs in console while running on locally.

This was working fine few days back, but not working now.

Below is the snippet of code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(sortable)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyselect)
                    
rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)  

      bsModal(id = "modalExample",title =  'Select Features and Re-Arrange ', 
      trigger =  "tabBut", size = "large",

      radioButtons('radio', 'Select Action', choices = 
                      list('Default' = 'Default', 'Custom' = 'Custom'),
                      selected = 'Default', inline = T),
      bucket_list(
        header = "Select Features and Re-Arrange", group_name = "bucket_list_group",
            add_rank_list(
              text = "Drag from here",
              labels =
                c("Code","To", "Name", "From","Desc","Distance"),input_id = "rank_list_1"
            ),
            add_rank_list(
              text = "To here", labels = NULL,
              input_id = "rank_list_2"),orientation = 'horizontal')
        )

main_df <- reactive({
  selected_action = input$radio

  if(selected_action == 'Custom' ){
    result <- rv$df %>%
              select(all_of(input$rank_list_2))
  }
  else{result <- rv$df}
  return(as.data.frame(result))
})

output$content <- DT::renderDataTable({
  if(is.null(main_df())) return()      
  DT::datatable(main_df(),
    selection = 'none', filter = 'top', editable = FALSE, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE)) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
main_df <- reactive({
    req(input$radio,input$rank_list_2)
    if(is.null(input$radio) | is.null(input$rank_list_2)) {return(NULL)}
       
    selected_action = input$radio
    
    if(selected_action == 'Custom' ){
      result <- rv$df %>%
        select(all_of(input$rank_list_2))
    }
    else{result <- rv$df}
    return(as.data.frame(result))
  })

output$content <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(main_df(),
                selection = 'none', filter = 'top', editable = FALSE, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE)) 
})
```

Comment: Still same problem. It won't work from the Link, but works locally. Do you have any other opinion?

Comment: Try `req(input$radio,input$rank_list_2)` inside `main_df`. Without looking at the full code, it is hard to identify where else there might be a problem.

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: If you are working remotely and the shiny server is in the company, you may need to connect to VPN before trying the link. Directaccess my not work.

Comment: Yes, I connected to VPN and trying the same URL. The URL will work correctly, if I removed that custom sortable and use normal renderdatatable.